# Discovering the VoIP connection parameters for CISCO 7961

Tags: voip

Not sure this question belong here, please redirect me to somewhere else in case.

I've a CISCO 7961, a VoIP phone, which receive its configuration from a company central server. I asked the IT people if they can tell me how the phone is configured to access VoIP services, for the simple reason that sometimes I would prefer to use a soft phone from my laptop. Since it seems it's difficult for them to give an answer, I wonder if there is some way to get such configuration from the phone itself (tried to navigate its menus, but no luck), or maybe by connecting it to a switch and sniffing the IP traffic it generates.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Network Configuration Menu](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7961g_7961g-ge_7941g_7941g-ge/6_0/english/administration/guide/6_0/7961net.html#wp1031235)

> **Displaying a Configuration Menu**
>
> To display a configuration menu, perform the following steps.
>
> Note You can control whether a phone has access to the Settings menu
>   or to options on this menu by using the Settings Access field in the
>   Cisco Unified Communications Manager Administration Phone
>   Configuration page. The Settings Access field accepts these values:
>
> - Enabled—Allows access to the Settings menu.
> - Disabled—Prevents access to the Settings menu.
> - •Restricted—Allows access to the User Preferences menu and allows volume changes to be saved. Prevents access to other options on the
>     Settings menu.
>
>   1. Press the Settings button to access the Settings menu.
>   2. Perform one of these actions to display the desired menu:
> - Use the Navigation button to select the desired menu and then press the Select softkey.
> - Use the keypad on the phone to enter the number that corresponds to the menu.
>
>   3.To display a submenu repeat Step 2.
>
>   4. To exit a menu, press the Exit softkey.
>
> **Network Configuration Menu**
>
> The Network Configuration menu provides options for viewing and making
>   a variety of network settings. Table 4-2 describes these options and,
>   where applicable, explains how to change them.
>
> **SIP General Configuration Menu**
>
> The SIP General Configuration menu displays information about the
>   configurable SIP parameters on the phone.

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately I still cannot find parameters like: username, password, SIP server.

Comment: Then it is back to IT :(